# Symfony2 HwioAuth - getting full profildetail from linkedin

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

i already opened yesterday a topic for my questions about hwioauthbundle in symfony2.
[Symfony2 HWIOauthBundle error with response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588062/symfony2-hwioauthbundle-error-with-response)

Thanks to stloyd for his answer, this helped me to figure it out how to use the bundle for getting access to linkedin.

I am trying now to get not only the formattedname from linkedin but also other informations like educations, skill s.o.

I am not sure if this is generally possible with HwioAuth?
That is my config.yml

```
hwi_oauth:
firewall_name: main
resource_owners:
    linkedin:
        type: linkedin
        client_id: %linkedin_client_id%
        client_secret: %linkedin_client_secret%
        scope: r_fullprofile
        infos_url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,educations,languages,skills)?format=json'
        scope:     'r_fullprofile'
        paths:
            educations: educations
            languages: languages
            skills: skills
```

That is my security.yml:

```
    providers:
     ....
     my_custom_hwi_provider:
        id: linkedin.oauth_user_provider

firewalls:
    main:
       ...
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                linkedin: "/login/check-linkedin"
            login_path: /login
            failure_path: /login
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: linkedin.oauth_user_provider
```

This is my service class Provider:

```
    <?php

namespace XXXX\UtilBundle\Util\OAuthProvider;

use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;

class Provider
{
   protected $session, $doctrine;
   public function __construct($session, $doctrine) {
       $this->session = $session;
       $this->doctrine = $doctrine;

   }



   public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
   {
      //data from LINKEDIN response
      var_dump($response);
      exit;
   }
 }
```

As you see i give_out the json what i get from linkedin. Hier is probally the response and the fields for educations, skills are empty!

```
    class HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\PathUserResponse#694 (4) {
 protected $paths =>
 array(8) {
'identifier' =>
string(2) "id"
'nickname' =>
string(13) "formattedName"
'realname' =>
string(13) "formattedName"
'email' =>
string(12) "emailAddress"
'profilepicture' =>
string(10) "pictureUrl"
'educations' =>
string(10) "educations"
'languages' =>
string(9) "languages"
'skills' =>
string(6) "skills"
}
protected $response =>
 array(1) {
 'id' =>
 string(10) "XYXYXYXYXYXYXY"
}
protected $resourceOwner =>
class HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner\LinkedinResourceOwner#699 (8) {
  protected $options =>
    array(8) {
    'authorization_url' =>
    string(49) "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization"
    'access_token_url' =>
    string(47) "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken"
    'infos_url' =>
    string(81) "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,educations,languages,skills)?format=json"
    'csrf' =>
    bool(true)
    'client_id' =>
    string(12) "XYXYXYXYXYXYXY"
    'client_secret' =>
    string(16) "XYXYXYXYXYXYXY"
    'scope' =>
    string(29) "r_fullprofile"
    'options' =>
    array(0) {
    ...
   }
  }
  protected $paths =>
   array(8) {
    'identifier' =>
      string(2) "id"
     'nickname' =>
       string(13) "formattedName"
     'realname' =>
       string(13) "formattedName"
     'email' =>
       string(12) "emailAddress"
     'profilepicture' =>
       string(10) "pictureUrl"
     'educations' =>
       string(10) "educations"
     'languages' =>
       string(9) "languages"
     'skills' =>
       string(6) "skills"
    }
    protected $defaultOptions =>
     array(6) {
      'client_id' =>
        NULL
      'client_secret' =>
        NULL
      'infos_url' =>
        NULL
      'user_response_class' =>
        string(54) "HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\PathUserResponse"
      'scope' =>
        NULL
      'csrf' =>
        bool(false)
     }
   protected $httpClient =>
   class Buzz\Client\Curl#700 (7) {
      private $lastCurl =>
      resource(286) of type (curl)
      protected $options =>
       array(2) {
       ...
    }
   protected $ignoreErrors =>
    bool(true)
   protected $maxRedirects =>
    int(5)
   protected $timeout =>
    int(5)
   protected $verifyPeer =>
    bool(true)
   protected $proxy =>
    NULL
  }
   protected $name =>
    string(8) "linkedin"
    protected $state =>
    NULL
    protected $storage =>
  class HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\RequestDataStorage\SessionStorage#701 (1) {
    private $session =>
      class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session#220 (3) {
      ...
   }
  }
    public $httpUtils =>
    class Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils#230 (2) {
    private $urlGenerator =>
    class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router#233 (9) {
     ...
    }
    private $urlMatcher =>
    class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router#233 (9) {
     ...
   }
  }
}
 protected $oAuthToken =>
 class HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\OAuthToken#696 (11) {
  private $accessToken =>
   string(179) "XYXYXYXYXYXYXY"
   private $rawToken =>
    array(2) {
     'expires_in' =>
     int(5183807)
     'access_token' =>
      string(179) "XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY"
   }
   private $refreshToken =>
  NULL
   private $expiresIn =>
   int(5183807)
   private $createdAt =>
   int(1378302276)
   private $tokenSecret =>
   NULL
   private $resourceOwnerName =>
   NULL
   private $user =>
   NULL
   private $roles =>
    array(0) {
   }
   private $authenticated =>
    bool(false)
    private $attributes =>
    array(0) {
    }
 }
```

}

In protected $oAuthToken => is the value 
private $authenticated =>
    bool(false)

Am i authenticated?
And how can i access other fields with r_fullprofile as scope from Linkedin?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [LinkedIn API client](https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client/) and its first example. You fetch stuff by

```
$linkedIn->api('v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName)');
```

Also, have a look at the [API documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields). It states clearly what fields you can fetch and how.